# How to express a feeling beyond proud?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

How to express a feeling beyond proud? For example, in the sentence:

> If one student is proud of knowing one thing, then a school is **honoured** to have thousand students who know many things

Here, I use the word *honoured* to express a feeling that is beyond proud.

Please correct the usage and suggest a better way of expressing it.

Comment: The feeling beyond *pride* is, of course, *hubris* ;)

Comment: The school is 'very proud'

Comment: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-more-proud-or-prouder) confirms a hunch of mine: 'Technically, as a one syllable word, it should be "prouder," but increasingly "more proud" seems just as common (or maybe it is easier to pronounce).' ('Technically' means 'according to the pseudo-rules'.)

Comment: very weakens the sentence

Comment: @DanBron that's a confusing and misleading statement - *hubris* means **excessive or dangerous pride** and so doesn't apply here.

Comment: If the school were a person it would be *busting his buttons*.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Did you notice the winky face? That indicates sarcasm. That is to say: the comment was *intentionally* and *deliberately* misleading, and the emoticon was the punchline: to disabuse you of the notion that it was meant to be taken seriously. If I could have drawn a tongue firmly inside a cheek, I would have. As it was, I did the best I could.

Comment: @DanBron I understand the "winky face" emoticon.  The OP might not.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I'm pretty sure *everyone* on the Internet, no matter what their mother tongue, understands ;) . Emoticons are the universal language ;) .

Comment: @DanBron please stop ending sentences with semicolons.  Also your closing parenthesis is not matched with an opening one.  :P

Comment: @CandiedOrange Oops, sorry, must have dropped them, here they are: (( . And here are the missing bits from the semi- colons: .. . Sorry about that, hope you can reassemble them ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "**even prouder**" -

> If one student is proud of knowing one thing, then a school is even prouder to have a thousand students who know many things.

"honoured" doesn't have exactly the same meaning as "proud" and so shouldn't be used to mean "even more proud".

Comment: If you indent a paragraph, it doesn't cause it to become a blockquote, but rather "preformatted text", which by design will never word-wrap. This makes it hard to read, particularly on mobile devices, which are necessarily narrow. Indentation aka preformatted text is intended for source code and things like ASCII Art; blockquotes, formed by prefixing the text with a `>`, is better for prose.

Comment: @DanBron - understood, will edit, thanks. Oh wait you've already done it. thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I only mention it because I'm on a phone and I'm selfish!

Comment: @MaxWilliams "even prouder" suits best in my context.

Comment: I was going to post the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Honoured is not the next level of pride.

You have pride when you acknowledge your own accomplishment.  You are honored when someone else acknowledges your own accomplishment and communicates this fact.

Consider

> If one student is proud of knowing one thing, then a school is **pleased** to have **a** thousand students who know many things.

It's not the next level either but it gets the point across.

Comment: thanks for that. I will keep this in mind. But for my current context, "even prouder" suits best.

Answer (score 0):

How about "jubilant"

`feeling or expressing great happiness and triumph.
"a large number of jubilant fans ran on to the pitch"`

or "triumphant"

```
feeling or expressing jubilation after a victory or achievement.
"he couldn't suppress a triumphant smile"
```

or, although it is often defined as having the opposite meaning, "humbled"

```
Your Majesties, ... dear sisters and brothers, today is a day of great happiness for me. I am humbled that the Nobel Committee has selected me for this precious award....
```

Regarding "humbled", see this post: [What is the meaning of "I am humbled"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/what-is-the-meaning-of-i-am-humbled#answer-240557)